docker build return error: error getting credentials
I am follow this guide and stuck from here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/#build-the-apps-image
Here is the error I got:
sudo  docker build -t getting-started .
Password:
[+] Building 1.2s (1/2)                                                                             docker:desktop-linux
[+] Building 1.4s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                    docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 181B                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                    1.5s
------
 > resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
   2 |     
   3 |     FROM node:18-alpine
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: ``

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/aiad8a846r60lwxzkteeqi3xn

Can someone help? Thanks so much

your issue is with logging in to docker, this post might help you to solve your issue.
